# Issue with appendChild in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    //cards
    $(".card").each(function () {
        //capture the data-* sets
        var img = this.dataset.img,
            alt = this.dataset.alt,
            heading = this.dataset.heading,
            text = this.dataset.text,
            url = this.dataset.url,

            //set the template
            template = '<img src="' + img + '" alt="' + alt + '"> <h3>' + heading + '</h3> <p>' + text + '</p>';

        //append the template to the parent
        this.appendChild(template);

    });

});
```

I am trying to do the following:

Create a div with a data-(img,alt,url,heading,text) and then for each of those divs, I want to inject a template.

However, when I get to the last line of the code, chrome dev tools gives me this error: "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

I do not understand what is going wrong, "this" is the current $(".card") being looped over and i am only appending a child of the template variable, by my thinking, this should work...

thanks for reading and I hope you can help because I am stumped.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle example to test out ?

Comment: `template` is not of type `Node`, is of type `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're already using jQuery, why not just use:

```
$(this).append(template);
```

Keep in mind that `this` within a jQuery `.each()` loop is a reference to the current *DOM node*. If you want to treat it like a `jQuery` object, you need to wrap it (`$(this)`).

To explain the actual error message:

> "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

It's not complaining that `this` isn't "of type 'Node", it's complaining that `template` isn't. The `domNode.appendChild()` method only accepts actual DOM nodes, whereas jQuery's `$().append()` is far more robust (accepting a DOM node, another jQuery collection, an HTML string, etc.).

Comment: @RickHitchcock `domNode.appendChild()` doesn't accept an HTML string.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Haha, it actually took me a second to think about it after reading your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

`appendChild` expects an actual element (of type `Node`), not a string, so you have to do this in pure JS:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('alt', this.dataset. alt)
    image.setAttribute('src', this.dataset.img)
this.appendChild(image);

var header = document.createElement('h3');
    header.textContent = this.dataset.heading;
this.appendChild(header);

var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph = this.dataset.text;
this.appendChild(paragraph);
```

Create each element and append it the the parent one after the other like the above. There is of course the easy jQuery solution which *does* take a string: `$(this).append(string);`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $(this) and not this and append not appendChild

```
   $(this).append(template);
```

another solution will be

```
   this.innerHTML += template;
```

Comment: Actually if he/she doesn't want to use JQuery, he/she can use appendChild. The only thing is that the element must be created with `createElement` first :)

Comment: as i see he/she created a html string

Comment: Indeed! But it's not a 'must' to use jQuery ;)