# TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to append an existing div to have a particular design along with an error message extracted out of an array.

This was my attempt:

```
    if (data.errors.firstName) {
        document.getElementById("firstName").classList.add("has-error");
        document.getElementById("firstName-group").appendChild('<div class="help-block"> </div>');
    }
```

But it resulted in an error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Which after researching means that is a string which I can add in as it is not a valid dom node.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with appendChild in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657148/issue-with-appendchild-in-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is returning a string rather than the div node. appendChild can only append a node

```
var d= document.createElement("div");
d.classList.add("help-block");
document.getElementById("firstName-    group").appendChild(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a string value to `appendChild`, it has to be a `Node` which you can create using `document.createElement`, like so:

```js
document.getElementById("firstName").classList.add("has-error");
let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
document.getElementById("firstName-group").appendChild(helpBlock);
```

```css
.has-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.help-block {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.help-block::after {
  content: 'i am the help block';
}
```

```html
<div id="firstName-group">
  <div id="firstName">first name</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error reports, `parentNode.appendChild()` requires a DomNode as its argument; however if you must pass HTML strings instead then you could, instead, use `parentNode.append()`:

```
if (data.errors.firstName) {
    document.getElementById("firstName").classList.add("has-error");
    document.getElementById("firstName-group").append('<div class="help-block"> </div>');
}
```

Note, though, that this is considered by MDN – seethe linked reference, below – as “experimental,” so check compatibility before use.

References:

- [`parentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).